# My app is crashing on button click

Tags: android

I have 3 buttons in my application, 
buttons id's = button1, button2, button3.
button1 and button3 need to do the same action, exit the game - working.
button2 need to add 1 to a counter and change a text to the counter (using for a score)
so i made an int counter=0, tried to make the script and the app crashes when I press on button2, here's the logcat and the script:

```
package com.example.bluetap;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.graphics.Color;
 import android.graphics.drawable.PaintDrawable;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;

   public class FirstActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private TextView changingTextView;
private Button button1;
private Button button2;
private Button button3;
private int counter=0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    changingTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.changingTextView);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this); 
}
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();

    if (id == R.id.button1) {
        finish();
        System.exit(0);

}

    else if (id == R.id.button2) {
        counter++;
        changingTextView.setText(counter);

        }   


    else if (id == R.id.button3) {
        finish();
        System.exit(0);

                    }

                }

            }
```

here's the main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.bluetap.FirstActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:text="Press The White Button"
    android:textColor="@color/blue" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:text="Press The White Button"
    android:textColor="@color/blue" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:text="Press The White Button"
    android:textColor="@color/blue" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/changingTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="60sp" />
```

here's the logcat:

[image]

Comment: Your LogCat is unreadable. Please paste the text of the stack trace into your question, not a screenshot. You can get the text by selecting the lines of the stack trace and copying that text to the clipboard using Ctrl-C.

Comment: The screenshot is unreadable. Can you please copy the logcat to the question?

Comment: A suggestion : Use switch-case instead of if, else if inside `onClick()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have problem on:

```
else if (id == R.id.button2) {
        counter++;
        changingTextView.setText(counter);

        }
```

you can't set integer value to TextView, so you need cast that to String.

you can use:

```
 changingTextView.setText(""+counter);
```

or

```
changingTextView.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
```

or

```
 changingTextView.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
```

Answer (score 3):

`TextView.setText(int)` expects a resource identifier. You're trying to show the actual int value in your `TextView`. Android looks for a resource with that value, which it cannot find. Thus crashing your application.

Use `changingTextView.setText(String.valueOf(counter));` to convert it to a `String` first.

Comment: to convert it to a string I use this:     <string name="counter">counter</string>

Comment: Just replace your line with the line I provided.